# Something is causing my page to keep loading in the center?

Tags: javascript

I've been able to narrow down where the 'error' occurs, which is within the credit card form section:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cardNumber">Your card number</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input
                type="tel"
                class="form-control card-number input-medium"
                name="cardNumber"
                placeholder="Enter Your Valid Card Here"
                autocomplete="cc-number"
                required autofocus
                value=""
        />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cardNumber">Your Email Address</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input
                type="email"
                class="form-control"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Enter Your Valid Email Here"
                required autofocus
                value=""
        />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My suspicious are that the form I'm using (which uses the Stripe API) has a customer error reporting feature, so if for example the customer's card has expired then an error pops up just above the 'form-group' code shown above - and also in the php and javascript there is a reference to .index.php which is at the bottom of the page here:

```
<script>
  $('.close').click(function(){
  window.location.href='index.php';
  });
 </script>
```

But that's only my hunch....

Any ideas why this page is behaving like this? Thanks!

Comment: Try to exclude js scripts from your page one by one.

Comment: What about the `autofocus` attribute of both input fields? Although those seem to be below the viewpoint...

Comment: @Rick - Thank you! Yes that was it.....do you think it is safe to remove that? My understanding is that the attribute in the form is... "[to specify]  that an <input> element should automatically get focus when the page loads..." That's from W3. Of course I can test but just wondering if you guys think of a reason to keep it?

Comment: The only reason to keep it, is if you want the user to be able to directly begin typing (that's what it says basically: put the cursor in this field). So it doesn't make sense to have both fields get autofocus. Furthermore, I suppose the user will be reading some stuff before filling in his credit card details, so he won't mind first selecting the field before typing, I think.

Comment: @Rick - thanks. I'll go with that and just try testing without 'autofocus. Appreciate it - thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer = remove 'autofocus' - thanks to @Rick

Comment: The OP can't as no one posted one